# Proxy app which doesn't requie any root access in android 2.3.6

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, proxy

I recently installed [proxydroid app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.proxydroid) in my android 2.3.6 This application requires root access. Every time to use it, I need to make root access to my device.
Is there any proxy app which does not require any root access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer: No.

Long answer:

No, as these app use a native binary installed onto the system to reroute data through the proxy. This is done at kernel level (actually it's done using the terminal commands, but it is done at kernel level), because of this root access is needed.

There are **0** apps that allow you to use a proxy without rooting first. Android 4.x natively supports proxies however.

Comment: I was not aware of this fact about proxy in android 2.3. Amazing... Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

#### Short answer:

No, proxy apps available on the playstore all need root (to my knowledge). **But you can use the native proxy -- even with Android 2.1.**

#### Longer answer:

As [Liam wrote](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/37821/16575) in his answer, an explicit proxy requires kernel level access. But Android has a native proxy built in.

Before Android 4.x, its settings were simply hidden. So all you need is access to its settings page -- which is what some apps provide, as e.g. [Proxy Settings](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lechucksoftware.proxy.proxysettings) does:

[image: Proxy Settings]

From the app's description:

> It provides a set of tools to ease the access and the modification of the proxy configuration into your Android device. **Proxy Settings** offers to the users a set of tools to check and troubleshoot the selected proxy configuration

*Proxy Settings* works with Android 2.1 and higher.

Comment: This doesn't actually work. It never did for me at least. Maybe that is why they were hidden...

Comment: I never needed them, so I never tried them. I just remember there was one more app giving access to those settings -- just could not find it. Ah, I'm stupid! I mentioned it in one of my books... Here it is: [HTTP Proxy-Settings](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.credil.proxysettings)